# One universal function for JS POST AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using `$.post` function in Javascript to send variables to php file, and to get output from php and show it on the page.

For now I got >30 repeating similar codes block for each page, which seems not so efficient:

```
  $(document).on('click', '#forgotpass', function() {
    var forgotpwd_email = $('#emailreg').val();
    ....
    $.post('include/forgotpwd_link.php', {
        forgotpwd_email: forgotpwd_email,
        ....
    }, function(a4) {
        $(".loginright").html(a4);
    });
  });
```

Where:

`#forgotpass` - id of button which activates the script

`#emailreg` - id of field with value which to be sent to php file

`.loginright` - class of div, where I place response

Every time id of button, field's id, **number of fields and variables**, and php file name are changing.
Any method to make a function with changing number of fields, which can be activated i.e. like below?

```
post_function('#button_id', '{variable1, variable2}', 'div with response from file_name.php','file_name.php');
```

Main challenge that number of variables to be sent is not defined.. it can be one to fifteen.

Comment: Just group all your fields into an object. When passing data in post, it's passed as an object anyway. You are on the right track, it's just your second argument doesn't need to be a string.

Comment: Alternatively, you could send an array of identifiers as your second argument, then have your `post_function` iterate over them to build the data object for the post request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to El_Vanja for hint.

In the end I have created following function:

```
function ajax_post(variables, response_selector, phpfile) {
        $.each(variables, function(key) {
          variables[key] = $('#'+key).val();
        });
        $.post(phpfile, variables, function(response) {
            $(response_selector).html(response);
        });

}
```

and to call it I'm adding inputs ID (i.e. #var1 and #var2) to **variables** object:

```
var variables = {var1 : '', var2 : ''};
```

and call function:

```
ajax_post(variables, '.wrapper', 'test.php');
```

where

**variables** - object with inputs ID (also used as variable name)

**.wrapper** - div where I want to place response from **test.php** file